# flask передача нескольких аргументов в адресной строке через слэш

Tags: python-3.x, flask

мне нужно через слэши указать несколько чисел в адресной строке, чтобы функция вернула самое большое из них.

```
@app.route("/max_number/<numbers>")
def max_number(numbers):
    split_strings = numbers.split('/')
    split_numbers = []
    for nums in split_strings:
        split_numbers.append(nums)
    max_num = max(split_numbers)
    return f'Максимальное переданное число  {max_num}'
```

Хотел обработать всё как единую строку, но следующий слэш отделяет numbers, а не входит в эту строку. Каким образом это можно решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Явно использовать [Variable Rules](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules).

Когда просто пишешь имя аргумента, то используешь variable rule типа `string`. Почти все variable rules игнорируют слэши. Кроме `path` - то, что нужно.

```
@app.route("/max_number/<path:numbers>")
def max_number(numbers):
    split_strings = numbers.split('/')
    split_numbers = []
    for nums in split_strings:
        split_numbers.append(nums)
    max_num = max(split_numbers)
    return f'Максимальное переданное число  {max_num}'
```

Comment: Преобразование строк к `int` (`float`) нужно добавить. Иначе `max` вернет некорректный результат.

Comment: @ioprst вы абсолютно правы, не заметил сразу, а преобразование действительно необходимо